# Cast object ( UIViewController ) to their unknown subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have developed a generic controller for sliding UIView and I manage UIViewController (and obviously subclass ) and must call a specific method (freeze) only if a subclass of UIViewController respond to this method:

```
-(void)freezeRootViewController
{
    if([_rootViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(freeze)])
        [ ((id) _rootViewController) freeze];
}
```

I don't know the class of _rootViewController but I know it is a subclass of UIViewController, for this reason I have tried to cast my _rootViewController to ID, but I can't compile:

Environment: XCode 4.5.1, iOs 4.3+ with ARC

Error: "No know instance method for selector 'freeze'"

Note: I CAN'T force the developer to use a specific UIViewController subclass for the _rootViewController.

Comment: Isn't this a *warning* rather than an error?

Comment: @H2CO3 No, XCode 4.5.1, iOs 4.3+ with ARC, don't compile.

Comment: see my answer, this should help (btw making this an error is brainless).

Comment: this is also not related to the version of Xcode, neither the version of clang/GCC, it seems to be related to ARC being used.

Comment: Import a header file that defines the `freeze` method. That will make the compiler happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a *warning* rather than an error - you *should* be able to compile your code and just ignore this diagnostic message. However, if you want to get rid of it completely, you can declare a protocol and do the cast as follows:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)freeze;

@end

[(id <MyProtocol>)_rootViewController freeze];
```

Comment: No it's an Error, but if I add only the protocol to my class (without cast!!) all work perfectly! Thank you ;)

Comment: @Kappe Please accept/upvote my answer when you are able to do so, thanks.

Comment: @H2CO3: Just as a note: With ARC, you cannot compile an unknown method selector. See e.g. http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2012/Jul/msg00114.html where it is said that it was a deliberate decision to make this an error instead of a warning.

Comment: @MartinR And it still doesn't make sense (thanks for the link, by the way). If a method returns `id`, the compiler can still issue a strong/weak reference; if it doesn't (or if the return value is cast), it should not do anything.

Comment: I would have to disagree with this method. Kappe checked `respondsToSelector:` so therefore `performSelector:` should be used. Before casting to protocol you should check if it `conformsToProtocol:`.

Comment: "Kappe checked respondsToSelector: so therefore performSelector: should be used" -No, it doesn't. "Before casting to protocol you should check if it conformsToProtocol:" technically, you don't *have to*. And you can also make the protocol a part of the API you're exposing, in this case absolutely no checking would be required.

Comment: I did not say it has to be used, I said it should. I know this would work, which is why I did not downvote, but if your recommending for it to be cast to a protocol, I would also recommend checking if it conforms to the protocol instead.

Answer (score 2):

After checking if a "generic" type responds to a selector you invoke it by using `performSelector:`/`performSelector:withObject:` if it is a simple 0-1 parameter method, otherwise use an [`NSInvocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Since `freeze` has no arguments you would just use `performSelector:`.

```
-(void)freezeRootViewController
{
    if([_rootViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(freeze)])
        [_rootViewController performSelector:@selector(freeze)];
}
```